# GasService in android logcat

Tags: android, service, logcat

I've got a few errors in my logcat that keep on repeating every second or so, but I don't understand where they come from ?

`1539  1547 E GED     : Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
1539  1547 E GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
1539  1547 E GED     : Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
1539  1547 E GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
1060  1161 E ApplockRunningService.TAG: AppLockService------------->tasks = [android.app.ActivityManager$RunningTaskInfo@40598b4]
1060  1161 E ApplockRunningService.TAG: AppLockService------------->packname = com.android.launcher3
1060  1161 E ApplockRunningService.TAG: getLockFlag------------> c = android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@a210cdd`

When listing the android services, there is no such "GasService";
there is also no "Gas" process listed with "ps".

Additional info: the process 1539 is launched by /vendor/bin/ged_srv
which is a binary file that is not visible except by root :-/

So, where do these errors come from ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **GasService** see => GpuAppSpectatorService

native:

```
/system/bin/gas_srv

/system/lib/libgas.so
```

pkg:

```
com.mediatek.GpuAppSpectatorService
```

init:

```
on property:sys.boot_completed=1
    start gas_srv

service gas_srv /system/bin/gas_srv
    class core
    user system
    group system
    disabled
```

se policy:

```
/system/bin/gas_srv    u:object_r:gas_srv_exec:s0
```